# count repeat callers per day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table and I am trying to use SQL to show number of return calls when a extrnal_numbers first call is "abandoned" and then the next call that day is answered by a "user"

| external_number | call_id | date_started | date_connected | category | target_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12324 | 4699315612876800 | 2021-03-14T12:51:24.453000 | 2021-03-14T12:52:13.613000 | incoming | call_center |
| 12324 | 6246986274242560 | 2021-03-14T12:52:06.280000 | 2021-03-14T12:52:14.334000 | incoming | user |
| 12324 | 5846017495465984 | 2021-03-16T12:32:17.853000 | null | abandoned | office |
| 12324 | 4598643760496640 | 2021-03-16T12:38:25.682000 | null | abandoned | department |
| 12324 | 5957902265942016 | 2021-03-16T12:40:08.024000 | 2021-03-16T12:41:09.847000 | incoming | call_center |
| 12324 | 5244220798074880 | 2021-03-16T12:41:03.765000 | 2021-03-16T12:41:09.978000 | incoming | user |
| 12324 | 5957902265942019 | 2021-03-16T15:40:08.024000 | 2021-03-16T12:41:09.847000 | incoming | call_center |
| 12324 | 5244220798074881 | 2021-03-16T15:41:03.765000 | 2021-03-16T12:41:09.978000 | incoming | user |

Ideally I would like to see something like this

| external_number | call_id | date_started | repeat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12324 | 6246986274242560 | 2021-03-14 | no |
| 12324 | 5244220798074880 | 2021-03-16 | yes |

added detail, a call can show up more than once in a day, I only want to count repeat calls when the first call is "abandoned"

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly this is how you can do it :

```
SELECT c.external_number
     , c.call_id
     , c.date_started
     , c.date_connected
     , c.category
     , c.target_type
     , CASE WHEN c.category <> LCAT THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN  c.category <>c.Rcat THEN 'No'
       END AS repeat
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , LAG(category,1,'NA') OVER (PARTITION BY external_number ORDER BY date_started) Lcat
        , LEAD(category,1,'NA') OVER (PARTITION BY external_number ORDER BY date_started) Rcat
    FROM calls
    WHERE ( category = 'incoming' and target_type = 'user') OR category = 'abandoned'
) c
WHERE 
(c.category <> Lcat OR c.category <>c.Rcat)
AND c.category <> 'abandoned'
```

the way this query works is that it looks for the rows that are in "incoming" category and have target_type ='user' or the ones that are in "abandoned" category because the are the ones that we care , then we look at the previous or next category in each row and it detects if there is a change in the category and and reports them

note:

1. repeat will report yes for any call after its been abandoned even if before there were no successful call .
2. this query is per external_number only , if you need the result to be for example per external_number , per day  ; you need to adjust partitions accordingly

Comment: I'm using bigquery and it doesn't seem to like LAG(category,1,category) or  LEAD(category,1,category)  does  LAG(category,1) do the same thing?

Comment: that's weird ! [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions) shows it gets 3 params

Comment: the 3 parameter is the default value if it can't find previous value, however if you remove it you get null values which with some minor changes in the query you can handle it , but the query in the answer should work

Comment: I got it working with taking out the 3rd parameter, now I just need to make it per day as well would that just look like (PARTITION BY external_number, date(date_started) ORDER BY date_started)

Comment: with the 3 parameters I keep getting this error "Error running query
Argument 3 to analytic function 'lag' has to be a constant. Found Deref."

Comment: in anycase Thanks So much! super helpful getting me going figuring this one out

Comment: oh ok ,seems like default expression should be `constant expression ` only

Comment: you are welcome , please accept as asnwer if  it helped

Comment: hmm now I just need to figure out how to get this to work by day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230288/discussion-between-eshirvana-and-robin-fay).